# Error al conectarse: acceso denegado para el usuario ''@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy recibiendo datos de unas variables mediante url y esos mismos valores los quiero insertar a una base de datos MySQL, sin embargo me tira un error:

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Medical\views\agregardoc.php on line 17
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\Medical\views\agregardoc.php on line 17"

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include "conexionBD.php";
$idpaciente=$_GET["cp"];
$iddoctor=$_GET["cd"];
$estado='1';
$consulta="select id_paciente,id_doctor,status from relaciones";
$encontrado=0;
$resultado=$bd->consultar($consulta);
    foreach ($resultado as $row){
        if($row["id_paciente"]==$idpaciente && $row["id_doctor"]==$iddoctor && $row["status"]=='1'){
            $encontrado=1;
            $respuesta="El doctor seleccionado ya es su doctor";
    }
}

if($encontrado==0){
        mysql_query("insert into relaciones (id_paciente,id_doctor,status) values ('$idpaciente','$iddoctor','$estado')");
        $respuesta="Doctor agregado correctamente";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lo que te dice el mensaje de error es que no estas usando los parametros correctos (usuario y contraseña) para conectarte en la base de datos. Revisa el archivo conexionBD.php que estas usando y prueba en localhost/phpmyadmin el usuario y contraseña que allí aparecen.

Comment: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`= falta el nombre de usuario (aparece del lado izquierdo del @ en los mensajes de error: usuario@servidor)
`(using password: NO)`  = falta la contraseña si es q usa (no es seguro pero podes tener un usuario sin contraseña)

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a Stack Overflow y enhorabuena por tu primera colaboración. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y así ganar tu primera medalla), y responde a los usuarios que tengan dudas para que te puedan ayudar mejor. Suerte con la pregunta!

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en este caso se le califica como correcto a su propia respuyesta cierto? por que fue el quien encontró su propia solución

Comment: Como nota aparte, este código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de producción.

Comment: @ShadowPaz encontró la respuesta correcta él mismo. Pensaba que iba a faltar información, pero no. Ha sido una interesante, no sabía que ese era el fallo que se daba en estos casos.

Comment: mucho menos yo pero entonces para estasituación le calificaré correcta por que mi propuesta de solución iba encaminada para otro lado

Answer (score 2):

Te comento las conexiones a gestores de bases de datos requieren de:

> Te comento que revises que escribas correctamente los datos o
>   credenciales de acceso respetando minúsculas, si le cambias aunque sea
>   un caracter ya no será válido

1. Servidor **(si es tu propia pc es localhost, si es remoto coloca la IP del servidor)**
2. Usuario
3. Contraseña (**opcional, pero revisas si tu la necesitas para acceder**)
4. nombre de la base de datos

Te dejo dos ejemplos, los cuales dependen de que driver de conexión uses es decir o mysqli o pdo

**MYSQLI**

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "contrasenia", "basedatos");
```

**PDO**

```
$conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database","root", "contrasenia");
```

> Ya que como puedes notar te dice el error que la conexión no pudo ser
>   establecida y además menciona acceso denegado al usuario, por que no
>   usaste la contraseña de acceso

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por los comentarios, ya estaba utilizando una contraseña por eso me extraño el mensaje de error. lo resolví de la siguiente manera.

```html
<?php
include "conexionBD.php";
$idpaciente=$_GET["cp"];
$iddoctor=$_GET["cd"];
$estado='1';
$consulta="select id_paciente,id_doctor,status from relaciones";
$encontrado=0;
$resultado=$bd->consultar($consulta);
 foreach ($resultado as $row){
  if($row["id_paciente"]==$idpaciente && $row["id_doctor"]==$iddoctor && $row["status"]=='1'){
   $encontrado=1;
   $respuesta="El doctor seleccionado ya es su doctor";
 }
}

if($encontrado==0){
 $insertar_relacion="insert into relaciones (id_paciente,id_doctor,status) values ('$idpaciente','$iddoctor','$estado')";
 $res=$result=$bd->insertar($insertar_relacion);
  $respuesta="Doctor agregado correctamente";
 }
?>
```

cambiando la forma de insertar los datos ya que el que utilizaba era mysql antiguo por asi decirlo lo estaba combinando con PDO, por eso el error.